# issuse about cygwin and ms-dos style path

Tags: svn, path, cygwin

In cygwin environment, I exec the `svn info "D:\tmpsvn\code.txt"` command.

It has some warnings:

`cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: /cygdrive/d/tmpsvn/D:\tmpsvn\code.txt
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/d/tmpsvn/D:/tmpsvn/code.txt
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
svn: warning: W155010: The node '/cygdrive/d/tmpsvn/D:\tmpsvn\code.txt' was not
found.`

Why the path is translated into `/cygdrive/d/tmpsvn/D:\tmpsvn\code.txt`?

How can I exec the command correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use svn provided by cygwin. Download a command line version svn, and this will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, file path always contains /. No backslash (\) in the file Path. In Windows both work. The Backslash is the escape character. One more thing: Linux is case sensitive. Watch out for capital letters. Windows doesn't bother about capital letters.

Cygwin is a unix/linux environment simulation for windows.

You are using an absolute Path, while a relative path was expected.
Try the command 'pwd' to see what directory you are in right now. It means print working directory.
Try to modify your path prefix so it matches.

Comment: I use Phabricator, and `svn info` is called by `arc diff`, I can't do anything to control the path prefix.